# GCD: Type of dispatch_queue_t (dispatch_queue_s *)

Tags: grand-central-dispatch

There has been a post from an user who wants to know what this means:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) __attribute__((NSObject)) dispatch_queue_t captureQueue;
```

He is supposedly getting some errors and I thought I would google about it because I was also interested.

One thing led to another, which leads to my question here:

***What is the actual type of `dispatch_queue_t`?***

I also did some googling on it and found 2 questions in the past here on SO.
One basically focused on the suffix part, namely `_t`, in regards to the history of POSIX and C, so it doesn't answer my question.

Another is close, but the accepted answer was basically saying that it is a **typedef and no one is supposed to know**. And it is a **system-dependent type that has to deal with bits**.

That doesn't sit well with me being a curious person. And I thought there must be someone who knows or someone who knows better than I do, hence my question here.

---

If it is really true that no-one knows, then even an answer that tells me at least how this mechanism works in an abstract way and how its type is determined (BTW, runtime or compile-time?) according to the different bits of different OS would still be enough to satisfy me.

---

I also just looked at `queue.h` and `block.m`, what I found out is only this little piece of information:

```
typedef struct dispatch_queue_s *dispatch_queue_t;
```

And in `queue.h`, I saw this:

---

```
__OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_10_6,__IPHONE_NA)
DISPATCH_NONNULL_ALL DISPATCH_NOTHROW
void dispatch_async(dispatch_queue_t queue, dispatch_block_t block);
#endif

__OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_10_6,__IPHONE_NA)
extern struct dispatch_queue_s _dispatch_main_q;
#define dispatch_get_main_queue() (&_dispatch_main_q)
```

---

It's beyond my ken. I hope someone who knows very well GCD could share some knowledge on this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**TL;DR version:**

If your curiosity is simply to know what the fields are in `struct dispatch_queue_s`, you can read that for yourself in [this file](http://opensource.apple.com/source/libdispatch/libdispatch-339.1.9/src/queue_internal.h), but as a consumer/user of the API, you never need to know this information in order to use it. Because you never need to know, and because the fields in that struct are not part of the public API, if you use that knowledge (other than for your own edification and amusement), you are setting yourself up for trouble.

**Long version:**

Let's see if I can go one-by-one here:

> There has been a post from an user who wants to know what this means:
>
> @property (nonatomic, strong) **attribute**((NSObject))
>   dispatch_queue_t captureQueue; He is supposedly getting some errors
>   and I thought I would google about it because I was also interested.
>
> One thing led to another, which leads to my question here:

The [ARC Documentation](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#retainable-object-pointers) says this:

> Applying `__attribute__((NSObject))` to a property not of retainable
>   object pointer type has the same behavior it does outside of ARC: it
>   requires the property type to be some sort of pointer and permits the
>   use of modifiers other than assign. These modifiers only affect the
>   synthesized getter and setter; direct accesses to the ivar (even if
>   synthesized) still have primitive semantics, and the value in the ivar
>   will not be automatically released during deallocation.

Since you don't say what the issues were, it's hard for me to address them. I never use this myself, and from reading the documentation, it sounds like it's not recommended. I've certainly never needed this to get strong ARC semantics on a property holding a `dispatch_queue_t`.

On to the next thing:

> What is the actual type of dispatch_queue_t?
>
> I also did some googling on it and found 2 questions in the past here
>   on SO. One basically focused on the suffix part, namely _t, in regards
>   to the history of POSIX and C, so it doesn't answer my question.

OK, the `_t` suffix is a ["reserved namespace" that POSIX "called dibs on" way back when in POSIX.1](http://books.google.com/books?id=4Kb_1sKprCMC&pg=PA37&lpg=PA37&dq=underscore%20t%20posix&source=bl&ots=v8mCI4E_KR&sig=sTg4IISnX7vNNATRrJpfk_PklKs&hl=en&sa=X&ei=7CDyUsSTOurJygGsyYGQAQ&ved=0CEUQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=underscore%20t%20posix&f=false). All this means is that if you deign to use a suffix of `_t` on your types, POSIX won't promise that a newer version of the POSIX spec won't also declare a type with the same name that might break your code. In practice, you can go ahead and use the suffix if you like it, or if is helps you understand code better, or makes it look more POSIX-y, or whatever. Or don't use it. It's your choice.

> Another is close, but the accepted answer was basically saying that it
>   is a typedef and no one is supposed to know. And it is a
>   system-dependent type that has to deal with bits.

It's not that "no one is supposed to know" it's more that "consumers of this API are warned not to care" -- to treat pointers to this type as opaque.  Here is the typedef:

```
typedef struct dispatch_queue_s *dispatch_queue_t;
```

To dissect this a bit, this means that `dispatch_queue_t` is a pointer to a forward-declared struct called `dispatch_queue_s`. Consumers of the API do not need to know the layout of that struct, so the fact that it's *declared* but not *defined*, doesn't cause the compiler to barf. You work with things whose declaration is visible to you, but whose definition is not all the time (any time you call a library function like `printf` or `NSLog` or whatever.) By analogy, if I give you a street address (a pointer) to mail a letter to, you will assume that there is a building at that address (the pointed-to thing) but you don't need to know whether the building is a house, or an office building, or whatever, **if** the only interaction you have with it is by sending and receiving mail via its address.

Like `_t`, this is a future-proofing practice. If you treat a `dispatch_queue_t` (which is a pointer) as opaque, and Apple changes the internal structure of `struct dispatch_queue_s` in a future version, your code won't break. You never made any assumptions about the internals of it, because you didn't have that information.

> That doesn't sit well with me being a curious person. And I thought
>   there must be someone who knows or someone who knows better than I do,
>   hence my question here.

[`libdispatch` is open source](http://opensource.apple.com/source/libdispatch/libdispatch-339.1.9/), so you can go read pretty much everything there is to know about it. Again, it's not that you're "not supposed to know" it's more that you don't need to know in order to use it. If you really want to know, well... as they say, "Use the source, Luke." Cut to the chase? If your curiosity is to know what the fields are in `struct dispatch_queue_s`, you can read that for yourself in [this file](http://opensource.apple.com/source/libdispatch/libdispatch-339.1.9/src/queue_internal.h) but as a consumer of the API, you will never need to know this information in order to use GCD. FWIW, the GCD source can be a little hard to parse (lots of branch prediction hinting stuff all over the place, lots of `#defines`, etc.) so reading it may or may not actually help you understand what you're trying to understand.

> If it is really true that no-one knows, then even an answer that tells
>   me at least how this mechanism works in an abstract way and how its
>   type is determined (BTW, runtime or compile-time?) according to the
>   different bits of different OS would still be enough to satisfy me.

I hope I've been able to help with this. FWIW, these things are all known at compile time for the various "compile times" of each component. The layout of `struct dispatch_queue_s` was known at the time `libdispatch` was compiled by Apple and shipped with the OS. When *your* program compiles, it will know everything it needs to know, which is limited to "there is a structure, defined elsewhere, called `dispatch_queue_s` and I will interact with that structure using an opaque pointer."

Lastly:

```
__OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_10_6,__IPHONE_NA)
DISPATCH_NONNULL_ALL DISPATCH_NOTHROW
void dispatch_async(dispatch_queue_t queue, dispatch_block_t block);
#endif

__OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_10_6,__IPHONE_NA)
extern struct dispatch_queue_s _dispatch_main_q;
#define dispatch_get_main_queue() (&_dispatch_main_q)
```

This code is largely a red herring in your quest to understand opaque types. The first part is declaring the function `dispatch_async`, and the second is playing a little trick that says that there's a public global variable in another library (extern), of type `struct dispatch_queue_s` whose symbol is `_dispatch_main_q`, and whenever the preprocessor sees the string `dispatch_get_main_queue()` it should replace it with `(&_dispatch_main_q)`. This saves the overhead of a function call when people want to get a pointer to the main queue. It could just as easily have been declared as a completely opaque function like: `dispatch_queue_t dispatch_get_main_queue(void);` and defined in the library like:

```
dispatch_queue_t dispatch_get_main_queue()
{
    return &_dispatch_main_q;
}
```

...albeit with a minor performance hit. Hopefully this is helpful.